# Android: LatLng object to String format

Tags: android, coordinate-systems

I'm using the function `place.getLatLng()` and i need it as "31°47′0″N 35°13′0″E",
Is there a function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Location Api and formatting:

Get latitude and longitude from LatLang object then pass in following method-

```
private String convert(double latitude, double longitude) {
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

if (latitude < 0) {
    builder.append("S ");
} else { 
    builder.append("N ");
} 

String latitudeDegrees = Location.convert(Math.abs(latitude), Location.FORMAT_SECONDS);
String[] latitudeSplit = latitudeDegrees.split(":");
builder.append(latitudeSplit[0]);
builder.append("°");
builder.append(latitudeSplit[1]);
builder.append("'");
builder.append(latitudeSplit[2]);
builder.append("\"");

builder.append(" ");

if (longitude < 0) {
    builder.append("W ");
} else { 
    builder.append("E ");
} 

String longitudeDegrees = Location.convert(Math.abs(longitude), Location.FORMAT_SECONDS);
String[] longitudeSplit = longitudeDegrees.split(":");
builder.append(longitudeSplit[0]);
builder.append("°");
builder.append(longitudeSplit[1]);
builder.append("'");
builder.append(longitudeSplit[2]);
builder.append("\"");

return builder.toString();
```

}